# Python If/Else Statements

Tags: python

i am a bit of a newbie when it comes to python...

however i cannot get this piece of code to work. I have spent quite a while trying to figure out what is going wrong, in various books and question sites so i came here.

My python ***idle(Python GUI)*** (The Software i am using) Keeps on coming up with a syntax error when ever i use an Else statement...

```
a = str
print("What is Your name")
a = input()
b = str
print("Oh Hello " + a)
print("How Are You Feeling")
b = input()
if b == "Happy":
    print("Glad to hear that":
          else:
          print("Oh im sorry to hear that")
```

Sorry that it is a conversation WITH A COMPUTER but i never got to choose the topic so i could not help it...

Please help

Comment: It doesn't look like it is indented correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Indentation matters in Python. The `else` must be indented *exactly* the same amount as the `if` it pairs with:

```
a = str
print("What is Your name")
a = input()
b = str
print("Oh Hello " + a)
print("How Are You Feeling")
b = input()
if b == "Happy":
    print("Glad to hear that")   # Added the missing ) here as well
else:
    print("Oh im sorry to hear that")
```

Comment: `":)` you are going to get a syntax error with that `:` Aren't you ?

Comment: `:)` is the simply operator as defined in PEP-4242. It indicates the compiler that the preceding statement is not serious.

Comment: Wouldn't that be PEP-0401?

Answer (score 2):

The `else` statement needs to have the same indentation as its corresponding `if`. You are also missing a `)` at the end of your print and you don't need that `:` at the end of your print.

```
if b == "Happy":
    print("Glad to hear that")  # <== missing that last ), you don't need that :
else:  # <== indentation was wrong here
    print("Oh im sorry to hear that")
```